# loop through json for nested key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reddit

**What I'm trying to do:** get the jpg/gifv/video of the top posts of reddit aww and jquery append to html.

**My issue:** as i combed through a few different posts, i realise how complex the data is. there isn't a single specific key that presents the data.

- for jpg it is easy: it is the data.children.url
- however for gifv/video, they are everywhere. **but one common key is
  "fallback_url"**. but like i said, they are everywhere.

**what i mean by that:**

```
"media": {
              "reddit_video": {
                "fallback_url": "https://v.redd.it/8uxup7znzq121/DASH_1_2_M",



"reddit_video_preview": {
                "fallback_url": "https://v.redd.it/xstmcxt8hs121/DASH_1_2_M",


"secure_media": {
              "reddit_video": {
                "fallback_url": "https://v.redd.it/syxgtvfsrs121/DASH_9_6_M",
```

**Examples:**

- [example 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2i7h6/pup_wakes_up_to_the_sound_of_food/.json)
- [example 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2joq9/his_excitement_for_baths_can_not_be_contained/.json)

**My question:** is there a way to loop through the whole tree of data and find the specific key "fallback_url"? They are of different depth :/

**How i am going to use the data:**

if it is a video:

```
<video autoplay loop>
  <source src="https://v.redd.it/dkalanbuyo121/DASH_4_8_M"/>
</video>
```

if it is a pic or gif:

```
<img src="https://i.redd.it/ke4r7k9n7v121.jpg">
```

**Here's my working attempt at getting jpg/gif:**

```
$('#art').ready(function() {
$.getJSON("https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json?limit=1", function foo(result) {
  var posts = [];

  $.each(result.data.children.slice(0, 1), function(i, post) {

      posts.push(post.data);

  });


  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    $("#text").append('<h4>' + posts[i].title + '</h4>');
    $("#art").append('<img id=\"img" src=\"' + posts[i].url +'\"">');
  }
});
});

--html--
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="art" class="img column1">
    </div>
    <div id="text" class="comment column2">
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Post your html too, also show us expected output.

Comment: In this https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json?limit=1 I dont find any `fallback_url`.

Comment: @Justcode i have updated my html and here is the expected output: https://imgur.com/a/fzqgJcm. --- for this i used "art" instead of "aww" (https://www.reddit.com/r/art/hot.json?limit=1) because i haven't figured out the fallback_url

Comment: @Shashidhara sorry. I wasn't being very clear. the fallback_url are found in the json of each post. so "reddit.com/r/aww/hot.json?limit=1" will return a post, the permalink of the post will contain the fallback_url. eg. "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2joq9/his_excitement_for_baths_can_not_be_contained/.json", "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2i7h6/pup_wakes_up_to_the_sound_of_food/.json". so it is a two step process. I get a list of post from the "hot", then find the permalink of each post. then if the post has video/gifv content it will contain "fallback_url"

Comment: can you give us your JSON source? just some data is OK... I can't open your example links

Comment: @FadhlyPermata i tried clicking, they are working. but here are some example links: https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2i7h6/pup_wakes_up_to_the_sound_of_food/.json https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/a2joq9/his_excitement_for_baths_can_not_be_contained/.json then you could either put it into a jsonformatter or ctrl-f "fallback_url". sorry i'm new to this, i apologise if i didn't get what you mean

Comment: @KwokWenJian Sorry, my office connection forbid me to access reddit.com. So, you want to take the "fallback_url" values only?

Comment: @FadhlyPermata No worries~ i'd managed to find a solution :)